# Webpack: How to manually tell HMR compiler that files have changed?

Tags: webpack, webpack-hmr

I am using Webpack HMR in a setup where I use a Webpack loader to pre-compile some setting values into my files. These settings are all pulled from 1 JSON file.

I want to be able to:

1. update some settings in the JSON file
2. tell the Webpack compiler which files had settings that changed
3. compiler reprocesses those *original* files (before settings were injected), pulling in settings updates
4. HMR does its thing and updates the client

Sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/webpack-hmr-with-settings-nu2e9?file=/src/index.js

---

To do this I imagine I'm going to need to save a reference to all modules containing settings and their settings paths - so I know which files to mark as updated. Next, some kind of Webpack manifest manipulation?

Where would I start here?

Thanks